# Is OpenNI 2 compatibile with Windows 8.1?

Tags: compatibility, openni, asus-xtion

I installed OpenNI 2 on my MacBook Pro that runs Windows 8.1 natively with Bootcamp.
The sensor does his job perfectly on an older white MacBook with Windows 7 and OpenNI 2 but when I try to run NiViewer on the newer MacBook Pro it just says it cannot find a device.

Answer (score 0):

OpenNI 2.2 works perfectly fine on windows 8.1. I have tested it on a 64 bit Windows machine and I got good results. Check if you have installed all the drivers properly and try out all the USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had regarded specifically MacBook Pro Retina and ASUS Xtion. I'm not sure if all models are affected but it happened on my Intel i5 2013 and I think the same issue would apply to any OS.

The problem is due to some incompatibilities with (some or all I don't know) USB 3.0 ports.

The solution, luckily, is quite simple as ASUS, being aware of this, published a firmware update for Xtion 1080 which you can find here: [ASUS Xtion Support Page](http://www.asus.com/uk/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO/HelpDesk_Download/) (this link is for Xtion PRO but you can easily find the one for your device on ASUS website).

Obviously, as the Xtion won't connect to your laptop, to run the firmware update successfully you'll need to use another computer with OpenNI drivers installed so that your operating system can recognize the device and upload the firmware.